# Thomas write rula andview serializability

Tags: database-theory

Yesterday our Professor told in the class that Thomas Write rule ensures view serializability, but while surfing on this topic today on internet I am not able to find any information about that claim. So is it always $TRUE?$

What he told was this-->

> Timestamp ordering ensures conflict serializability
>
> Thomas write rule ensures view serializability

Comment: Did you just try asking your professor?

Comment: What to ask when he has already mentioned that in class... But i am not able to find a single line about it on the web

Comment: For instance, couldn't you say "You said that X. Is it really always true? Why?". Anyway, I hope your question attracts attention here.

Comment: Will do when college resumes on monday..Thanks anyway.. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Timestamp ordering ensures conflict serializability

**proof** :

Assume that in precedence graph of schedule, we have edge $T_i \rightarrow T_j$.

Now, When $T_j$ puts it's request for this conflicting operation it will be continue only if $\text{timestamp}(T_i) < \text{timestamp}(T_j)$.

Now, for schedule to be non conflict serializable there must exist a cycle in precedence graph of that schedule and let say that cycle is $T_i, T_{i+1}, ...., T_i$.

Now, note that that cycle can't exist because existence of cycle implies $\text{timestamp}(T_i) < \text{timestamp}(T_i)$. (As timestamp are unique.)

So, we conclude that there can't be any such cycle which in turn implies that timestamp ordering protocol allows only conflict serializable schedules.

Comment: Ya..this I know brother
but i want to confirm the claim about view serailizibility

Comment: Yes, working on that will post if succeed. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot.. :)

Comment: @Turing101, [here](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~welu/thomas.pdf) is a proof of second one

Comment: Thanks a ton mate.. :)